# Unity:Realtime lights not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using unity 5.5.2, recently after adding texture to the terrain the spot lights and point lights stopped working in some area of the terrain(refer down given photo for the problem and terrain setting).But when I remove the texture or decrease the Base map dist. to 0 the lights start to work again.

**Spotlight with texture**

[image]

**Spotlight before/after texture**
[image]

**Spotlight setting**

[image]

Comment: Check again shader of Terrain, try use standard shader.

Comment: Sorry, by accident i added a wrong normal map which created the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the normal texture, remove it if its wrong.